# Exim4 with outlook and other domain error

Tags: linux, email, linux-networking, outlook, exim

Sometimes when I try to send a mail to microsoft domain address I can see in exim4 mainlog lines like this :
`eur.olc.protection.outlook.com address already in use`
After hours or days in the exim4 queue, the mail has sent and sometimes client didn't receive it.

And Sometimes when I try to send a mail to another domain like gmail.com I can see line like this :
`address_mail_to R=dnslookup_users T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host`

I have tried this solution [quick fix](https://www.first2host.co.uk/f/cpanel-retry-time-not-reached-for-any-host/) it' works but the problem comes back again and again, I would like to fix this problem really

Answer (score 1):

you could check guideline in below page to troubleshoot, if it is still experiencing deliverability issues, you could contact Outlook.com deliverability support.

https://sendersupport.olc.protection.outlook.com/pm/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.%20[HE1EUR01FT057.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com

**Outlook.com Deliverability Support**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportrequestform/8ad563e3-288e-2a61-8122-3ba03d6b8d75